# Adding edittext to View layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Regarding this example - 
http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/05/detect-multi-touch-event-test-on-custom.html

How can I add EditText to the view ?
I tried to add it to the layout but when I'm trying to update it I'm getting error message.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice example here - http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle.
I added EditText to the layout and its working fine.

In order to use this example the code should be written as explained in [Sebastien's comment](http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/comment-page-1/#comment-11054), in which he uses parent as described in this line:

```
final Activity parent = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

The MultiTouchView from the link extends a View. You cannot add other Views to a View. You will need the MultiTouchView to extend a ViewGroup. See the android doc on building [custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

To be able to add views, I think replacing the following line in the sample code

```
public class MultiTouchView extends View {
```

with

```
public class MultiTouchView extends FrameLayout {
```

should work because FrameLayout is a subclass of ViewGroup. You may want to chose a different layout depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but ... when I changed View to FrameLayout the Application screen is empty.

Comment: Have you tried extending another layout like the RelativeLayout? Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, Its the same problem also with RelativeLayout. Do you have other example that demonstrate how to draw to the screen and also to have EditText on the same layout ?

Comment: I don't have an example for you but it doesn't take much. All you need to do is create a class which extends a ViewGroup (or subclass of ViewGroup). Let's say we extend the RelativeLayout. Now, to draw to the screen, all you need to do is override the onDraw(Canvas) in your class and call any of the various draw methods (The link from your question uses the drawCircle() method for example) to draw on the Canvas that is passed into the onDraw(Canvas) method.

Comment: Thanks, I found nice xample that is using parent for doing it and its working fine now.